# How different processes synchronize reads/writes from Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

What do we need to synchronize two processes that will get data from the same cassandra database?

Imaging that cassandra will need to store an "integer" value that changes values according to the a "request".

Initialy this value is zero, a new request comes and we call add(new_val) to add the new number to the existing in the db. Let's keep the scenario simple...

But what happens when two different requests write at the same time at the same point in the cassandra row? How do we ensure that the correct value is picked?
Is this something that cassandra offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are asking for is  a distributed lock, and in CAP terms you are asking for a consistent system.

Regarding the consistency part, Cassandra can be consistent if you follow the rule R+W > N, but then you are affecting your partition tolerance, where you build a CA system if you follow this rule instead of building an AP system which is the default usage.

Regarding the distributed lock, Cassandra doesn't allow this as far as I know, but you can use other systems (like Redis or zookeeper) to provide this functionality, but this of course increases your system's complexity and maintenance / monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, regarding distributed lock is there any example?